# What does "I had found the time to hover at some half a dozen jewellers' windows" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XI, published 1892)

> This characteristic scene, which has delayed me overlong, was but a moment in that day of exercise and agitation. To fit out a schooner for sea, and improvise a marriage between dawn and dusk, involves heroic effort. All day Jim and I ran, and tramped, and laughed, and came near crying, and fell in sudden anxious consultations, and were sped (with a prepared sarcasm on our lips) to some fallacious milliner, and made dashes to the schooner and John Smith's, and at every second corner were reminded (by our own huge posters) of our desperate estate. Between whiles, **I had found the time to hover at some half a dozen jewellers' windows**; and my present, thus intemperately chosen, was graciously accepted. I believe, indeed, that was the last (though not the least) of my concerns, before the old minister, shabby and benign, was routed from his house and led to the office like a performing poodle; and there, in the growing dusk, under the cold glitter of Thirteen Star, two hundred strong, and beside the garish glories of the agricultural engine, Mamie and Jim were made one. The scene was incongruous, but the business pretty, whimsical, and affecting: the typewriters with such kindly faces and fine posies, Mamie so demure, and Jim—how shall I describe that poor, transfigured Jim?

I've found several meanings of *hover* in the dictionaries but no one fits the context, I'm afraid. I suspect it could mean something like *bustle about swiftly* or *run to and fro* but I'm not sure.

Comment: In situations like this, if none of the dictionary definitions leap out as *obviously* the sense intended, you should make a point of trying to establish the "base" meaning (here, ***hover** = to stay in one place in the air, usually by moving the wings quickly*). If you can't extrapolate the context-specific intended meaning from that, check out the ***etymology***. In this case, that's **hover** *(v.) c. 1400, hoveren, frequentative of hoven "hover, **tarry, linger**"*, which should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but, to be honest, to make any etymology research or inquiry doesn't seem to me to be a reasonable way for an English language **learner**. If I'll ever reach this level of language skills I won't need to put any questions here. And, as you see, there is much difference between *hover = stay in one place in the air by moving wings like a colibri /hummingbird* and the verbs *tarry* and *linger*. In such a case I judge it legitimate *and* necessary to put the question. Please, don't get me wrong - I appreciate your suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: And even if I came across this "etymological" meaning I wouldn't know if it is the correct meaning in this context anyway. It's hard work to learn a foreign language.

Comment: Oxford Languages gives as its second definition **remain poised uncertainly in one place or between two states. - 
"her hand hovered over the console"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal meaning of "hover" is to remain flying in the air in one position.  Helicopters, kestrels, hummingbirds and some flies are able to hover.  While hovering, the animal is able to quickly move off in any direction.

Metaphorically when one is hovering, one is waiting somewhere, but not fixed.  I might hover outside the railway station in my car when I am picking up my spouse.

Here I understand that the writer stopped outside several jeweller's windows (looking at the jewellery, ie window-shopping) but was able to move from one window to another (they didn't become fixed at one shop).

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by *not fixed*? Does that mean you are running  or walking around? How can I do that sitting in a car? Or does it mean you are agitated or anxious? And what does *the writer was able to move from one window to another and didn't become fixed at one shop* mean? Everybody is able to move from one shop window to another one.. What is the correlation between the word *hover* and that the writer is *able to move from one window to another*?

Comment: Either waiting or moving. Not agitated. Not nervous. The writer stopped at one window for a while, looked at the jewellery, then moved on.  In contrast to going inside, sitting down and engaging with the shop staff.

Comment: I think that the "and my present, thus intemperately chosen, was graciously accepted" wording (in the context of "improvis[ing] a marriage between dawn and dusk" suggests some jewelry *was* purchased.

Comment: @nobody - Certainly it does - but it was only purchased _after_ a period of window-shopping (i.e. he didn't start out knowing exactly what he wanted).

Comment: @nobody I would also presume that the present was a wedding ring.

Comment: "intemperately chosen" suggests this was all done in a rush, since he was trying to get the wedding done in a day.